# Installing with PIP in virtualenv?

Tags: virtualenv

I'm trying to wrap my head around virtualenv and pip still.

If I use pip to install a library, it doesn't matter where I 'cd' to, because it installs the libraries in the same place right (which i dont even know where that is)?  So I guess my question is, when I install something with pip, how do I make sure it only installs that library inside of my virtual environment?  Do I need to cd to that directory first?  or is there a command I'm supposed to use with pip to make sure it only installs to the virtualenv project I'm working in?

Answer (score 2):

Activate **virtualenv** first:

```
source virt_name/bin/activate
```

Then after that, install the libraries:

```
pip install module_name
```

*Note: Don't use sudo with pip because sometimes it will assume you want to install in /usr/local/lib/site-packages.*

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if you do not use virtualenv --system-site-packages  to create your virtualenv, you should be only working with your per-environment packages.
Providing you run the activate script before installing anything.

i.e. Do the following, if you want to install something in your virtualenv.

1. Run activate script

   1. Windows: [ve_directory]\Script\activate.bat
   2. Linux: source [ve_directory]/bin/activate
2. pip install [your requirements]

I think it doesn't matter where your current working directory is.

Reference:
http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#the-system-site-packages-option

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new environment with `virtualenv`, among other things it creates a `bash` script `venv/bin/activate` (where `venv` is the folder you specified when you created the environment; libraries are located there as well, by the way). When you run it in your shell the environment variables become arranged so that `pip` installs new libraries in this environment's folder. See [virtualenv docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for details, section "activate script".